# object returned from useHooks() passed as props not re-rendering child component after handleDelete from a list of members

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have this object coming down in the React tree (fetch first from a database for example)

```
const data = {
 time: "10am",
 stuff: "blah blah blah",
 members: ["member1", "member2", "member3"]
}
```

Having an App.js Component like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useHook } from "./useHook";

export default function App() {
  const { array, deleteGroupMember } = useHook();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.members &&
        array.members.map(m => {
          return (
            <button key={m} onClick={() => deleteGroupMember(m)}>
              {m}
            </button>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and a custom Hook where I want to delete a member after click -updating the member's array -

useHooks.js

```
import React from "react";

const data = {
 time: "10am",
 stuff: "blah blah blah",
 members: ["member1", "member2", "member3"]
}


export const useHook = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState({});
  console.log("array:", array);

  //
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setArray(data);
  }, []);

  // delete current group members
  const deleteGroupMember = member => {
    const result = array.members.filter(client => client !== member);
    setArray(result);
  };

  return { array, deleteGroupMember };
};
```

The component is not updating the list after one or more members are deleted.
I thought that anything you pass as props that changes will automatically re-render a component.
But nope, it's not working. Why?

I put a code sandbox example if you want to tinker with my code:

[link-to-my-code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-elgamal-dpllv?file=/src/useHook.js:0-474)

Comment: You're changing the type. when you start `array` is an object with a `members` key. but then when you delete a member you are setting the state to an array, so it's definitely going to break something

Comment: Thank you @Azium, really appreciate it also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change your state shape from `{ member: string[] }` to `string[]` after a delete. Save the filtered result array back into an object with key `members`.

```
// delete current group members
const deleteGroupMember = member => {
  const result = array.members.filter(client => client !== member);
  setArray({ members: result });
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-elion-d75ed]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Drew Reese, I'm still in shock, how could I be so blind OMG...I need to sleep.

Comment: Drew and/or Azium, and if my object has other properties and I still want to keep them?

Comment: For example: 

```
const data = {
  groupName: "Venceremos",
  members: [
    {
      full_name: "Alberto Garcia",
      uniqueId: "SsKU86ePH"
    },
    {
      full_name: "Andre Hernandez",
      uniqueId: "ycEAWRR8u"
    },
    {
      full_name: "Badiana Garcia",
      uniqueId: "1Qvl_ZDFo"
    }
  ],
  uniqueId: "lMJzdbKbU"
};
```

Comment: @waldothedeveloper Use the spread syntax so spread in all of the `array` object: `setArray({ ...array, members: result });` or combine with a functional state update to ensure multiple queued updates correctly use previous state: `setArray(array => ({ ...array, members: result }));`

Comment: I was stupidly doing this for no reason: setArray(array => ({ ...array, [array.members]: currState })); 
when I don't have a nested property oh gosh: